# DateTime.ParseExact Equivalent for VB6?

Tags: datetime, vb6

Does anyone know if there's an *actual* equivalent method in VB6 for .NET's `DateTime.ParseExact()` method?  I've tried using `DateSerial()`, `IsDate()` and `CDate()`, but, due to all of VB6's "helpfulness", I'm coming up with some unexpected results.

To be more specific, I'm trying to parse a text string from user input to validate whether or not it's an actual date.  As an example, I'll be using the date `8/25/16`.  The usual expected input may or may not have delimiters between the month, day and year, so it may be entered as `82516`.

Here's a sample of the code that's not working as intended (the value of `82516` is stored in the `TempStr` variable):

```
If IsDate(Format(TempStr, "#/##/##")) And IsDate(Format(TempStr, "##/#/##")) Then
    TempDate = #12:00:00 AM#
ElseIf IsDate(Format(TempStr, "#/##/##")) Then
    TempDate = CDate(Format(Tempstr, "#/##/##"))
ElseIf IsDate(Format(TempStr, "##/#/##")) Then
    TempDate = CDate(Format(TempStr, "##/#/##"))
End If
```

Using the stated value, the first condition triggers.  Knowing how it works, I understand why it's happening (it's "rearranging" the month, day and year to try to match a valid date), but I'm really trying to get it to parse the date in a specific order.  I know that .NET's `DateTime.ParseExact()` method would get me there, but I have to do this in VB6 (maintaining some legacy code).

I tried using `DateSerial()`:

```
If DateSerial(CInt(Right(TempStr, 2)), CInt(Left(TempStr, 1)), CInt(Mid(TempStr, 2, 2))) > #12:00:00 AM# Then
    If DateSerial(CInt(Right(TempStr, 2)), CInt(Left(TempStr, 2)), CInt(Mid(TempStr, 3, 1))) > #12:00:00 AM# Then
        TempDate = #12:00:00 AM#
    Else
        TempDate = DateSerial(CInt(Right(TempStr, 2)), CInt(Left(TempStr, 1)), CInt(Mid(TempStr, 2, 2)))
    End If
Else
    If DateSerial(CInt(Right(TempStr, 2)), CInt(Left(TempStr, 2)), CInt(Mid(TempStr, 3, 1))) > #12:00:00 AM# Then
        TempDate = DateSerial(CInt(Right(TempStr, 2)), CInt(Left(TempStr, 2)), CInt(Mid(TempStr, 3, 1)))
    Else
        TempDate = #12:00:00 AM#
    End If
End If
```

But that also comes along with an automatic correction if the values for any of the parameters fall outside of the acceptable ranges.

I also tried the following variation of the above code:

```
If IsDate(Format(TempStr, "m/dd/yy")) And IsDate(Format(TempStr, "mm/d/yy")) Then
...
```

But the first test results in an *entirely* different value of `3/12/26`, which is WAY off from the original input.

Is there any way to accurately emulate the .NET `DateTime.ParseExact()` method in VB6, or am I just going to have to toss these types of user input values out as invalid/ambiguous?

Comment: `82516` with no delimiters will be problematic because you will never know if it is the Day or Month which only has 1 digit. Is `11216` Jan 12 or  Nov 2?

Comment: I understand that, which is why I'm rejecting the input if it's totally ambiguous in that fashion, but `82516` SHOULD only return one valid date if the numbers are taken in the correct order (month, day, year).  For `11216`, the function should return an "empty" date (`12:00:00 AM`), but `82516` should return `8/25/16` if I can get VB6 to "ParseExact".

Comment: Just as a side note, I also have similar code for if the user happens to enter a four-digit year, but I didn't want to clutter up the question with the entire function I'm writing (plus, I'm doing my VB6 programming on an XP VM, and it won't let me copy/paste from there to here).

Comment: Are you able to add a COM exposed .NET assembly to your project? If so,  you could wrap ParseExact in a method that's exposed through COM for your VB6 app to use. If not, you could add some extra validation before calling any of the Date functions. Split the text and cast to Integer variables then check if the values are between acceptable ranges based on whether you think it's a month, day, or year. Depending on how many formats you have to support the code would get lengthy.

Comment: In interpreting strings as dates, VB6 will try several different formats to try and find one that is a date.  For your string 82516, and the ##/#/## format, this will be read as May 16 1982. Not a bug, just how it works, don't just think in terms of mm/dd/yy.  For instance, isdate("82/5/16")=True, datevalue("82/5/16")=5/16/1982, format("82/5/16", "mm/dd/yyyy")=05/16/1982.

Comment: @MarkL - I realize that, but I didn't think of it when I was first writing the code.  It wasn't until I went into testing that I remembered that VB6 tries to be "helpful" by trying multiple possibilities for a date value.  That's why I started looking for the `ParseExact` method.

Comment: @Marc - I've actually started working on a solution that implements the second of your suggestions.  I've built a separate function that explicitly splits the dates as intended and then recombines them as a date.  With that reusable function, I think I might be able to achieve the goal, even if it isn't exactly the `ParseExact` function.

I think that attempting to build and add a COM-exposed .NET assembly would be a bit more complicated when it comes to distributing the final solution in this environment, so I think I'm going to stick with trying to keep everything self-contained.

Comment: After further testing, I've come up with an issue that I don't know that I can solve programmatically.  The problem arises when an undelimited string of numbers is six characters long.  For example, `122016`.  I might assume that it's `12/20/2016`, but what if it's supposed to be `1/2/2016`?  I think I'm just going to have to impose a user requirement that the date is always six characters: two-digit month, two-digit day and two-digit year.  On the final submission of the form, I'll go ahead and confirm the date via MsgBox.  I think that's the best I'm going to be able to do.

Comment: Or provide a DateTimePicker control instead of a Textbox.  That's why we have them.

Comment: @Bob77 - I've thought of that, and would actually prefer it. The implementation is a bit more difficult because I'll have to do some work at each of the workstations to ensure that they have the necessary system files, but it may be worth it in the long term.

Comment: If you can change the UI, and don't want to use a DateTimePicker, you could use separate text boxes for the user to enter the day, month, and year. You would still have to do some validation but at least you are telling the user which part to enter in each and reduces the need to try and support many different formats. I guess it's always a trade off between complicated code or complicated UI.

Answer (score 1):

I will personally write a function for ensuring the correct date is returned -

First get the string/integer, break it down into chunks and add values to those chunks and return a combined date...

```
Option Explicit

Public Function MakeCorrectDate()

Dim xMakeDate As Long, xDay As Integer, xMonth As Integer, xYear As Integer, xCentury As Integer, strCorrectDate As String
''xMake as long because of size, strCorrectDate as string to allow the /...

xMakeDate = txtInput.Text

''Assuming the format will ALWAYS be the same days, months and year (12/20/16) and length is ALWAYS 6...
xDay = Left$(xMakeDate, 2)
xMonth = Mid$(xMakeDate, 3, 2)
xYear = Right(xMakeDate, 2)

''First get the correct part to 1900 or 2000...
If xYear = "00" Then
    xCentury = 20
ElseIf xYear < 99 And xYear > 20 Then ''Year 2000 and year 2020
    xCentury = 19
        Else
    xCentury = 20
End If

strCorrectDate = xDay & "/" & xMonth & "/" & xCentury & xYear

txtYear.Text = strCorrectDate

End Function

Private Sub cmdGetCorrectDate_Click()

If Not Len(txtInput.Text) = 6 Then
    MsgBox "Incorrect information, must be 6 or more characters."

    Exit Sub
        Else
    Call MakeCorrectDate
End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtInput_Change()

''Ensure the user adds only numerical text...
Dim WshShell As Object

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

If Not IsNumeric(txtInput.Text) Then
    WshShell.SendKeys "{BackSpace}"
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If the format is going to be less than 6 long, change the left, mid parameters as the last 2 will always be year - I assume..

Comment: This is similar to the solution that I've been writing and testing, but as stated in the comments above, I may have to break down and try to implement a date picker instead of a textbox if I want to be confident of the input.

Comment: Agreed, a DatePicker might be a solution depending on the conditions. If your user is to select dates way back in time then the picker might be cumbersome as they have to scroll through months and possibly years to get to the right date. What exactly is the circumstances for them when a date is added? I will amend my code above to make it as streamline for your user as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so here's what I've come up with as a solution for my current needs.  Similar to what @Andre-Oosthuizen posted above, I've decided to drastically simplify the validation from what I was doing before.  This series of functions requires the user to enter a six-digit date (two-digit month, two-digit day, and two-digit year).  I don't believe the century is going to be a factor in this specific application, so I'm going to leave that test out.

This should be acceptable to our users as they've had similar restrictions in other systems.  While I'd personally prefer a more "bullet-proof" solution (such as using a `DatePicker` or other manipulation of the UI), I think this is going to be the most effective for our environment.

```
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
' LostFocus event handler for the txtEffectiveDate TextBox.
' Test for a valid date when the user attempts to leave the field.
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub txtEffectiveDate_LostFocus()
    ' *********************************************************************
    ' ** Don't have the event handler try to do any parsing.  Just pass  **
    ' ** the .Text value to the validation function.  If a date comes    **
    ' ** back, reformat it to "look" like a date and move on.  Otherwise **
    ' ** pop up an "error" message and return focus to the TextBox for   **
    ' ** the user to correct their input.                                **
    ' *********************************************************************
    Dim TempDate As Date

    TempDate = CheckForValidDate(Me.txtEffectiveDate.Text)

    If TempDate > #12:00:00 AM# Then
        ' If a valid Date is returned, put the formatted String value
        ' into the TextBox and move on.
        Me.txtEffectiveDate.Text = Format(TempDate, "mm/dd/yy")
    Else
        ' If the Date value is not valid (#12:00:00 AM#), notify the
        ' user and refocus on the TextBox to force the user to
        ' correct the input before continuing.
        MsgBox "The date you entered was not valid." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
               "Please enter two digits for the month, two digits for the day and" & vbCrLf & _
               "two digits for the year." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
               "For example, today's date should be entered as either " & Format(Now, "mmddyy") & vbCrLf & _
               " or " & Format(Now, "mm/dd/yy") & ".", _
               vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "INVALID INPUT FORMAT"
        Me.txtEffectiveDate.SetFocus
        Me.txtEffectiveDate.SelStart = 0
        Me.txtEffectiveDate.SelLength = Len(Me.txtEffectiveDate.Text)
    End If
End Sub

'----------------------------------------------------------------------
' Attempts to convert the String input to a Date value.  If the String
' value is already a Date (i.e., "1/1/16" or similar), go ahead and
' assume that the user wants that date and return it as a Date value.
' Otherwise, strip any non-numeric characters and break apart the input
' to pass along for further validation.
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Function CheckForValidDate(ByVal DateStr As String) As Date
    Dim TempDate As Date

    If IsDate(DateStr) Then
        ' If the String value is already in a date format, 
        ' just return the Date value of the String.
        TempDate = CDate(DateStr)
    Else
        Dim TempStr As String
        Dim CurrentChar As String
        Dim TempYear As Integer
        Dim TempMonth As Integer
        Dim TempDay As Integer
        Dim I As Integer

        ' Strip all non-numeric characters to get a purely numeric string.
        For I = 1 To Len(DateStr)
            CurrentChar = Mid(DateStr, I, 1)

            If IsNumeric(CurrentChar) Then
                TempStr = TempStr & CurrentChar
            End If
        Next I

        ' The all-numeric string should be exactly six characters
        ' (for this application).
        If Len(Trim(TempStr)) = 6 Then
            Dim NewDateStr As String

            ' Break the numeric string into the component parts -
            ' Month, Day, and Year.  At six characters, there should
            ' be two characters for each element.
            TempMonth = CInt(Left(TempStr, 2))
            TempDay = CInt(Mid(TempStr, 3, 2))
            TempYear = CInt(Right(TempStr, 2))

            ' Now pass the individual values to the second part of
            ' the validation to ensure each of the individual values
            ' falls within acceptable ranges.
            NewDateStr = GetValidDateString(TempMonth, TempDay, TempYear)

            ' If the returned String value is not empty, then convert
            ' it to a Date value for returning to the calling method
            If Len(Trim(NewDateStr)) > 0 Then
                TempDate = CDate(NewDateStr)
            End If
        End If
    End If

    CheckForValidDate = TempDate
End Function

'----------------------------------------------------------------------
' Using numeric values for Month, Day, and Year, attempt to build a
' valid Date in mm/dd/yy format.
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Function GetValidDateString(ByVal intMonth As Integer, ByVal intDay As Integer, ByVal intYear As Integer) As String
    Dim ReturnStr As String

    ReturnStr = ""

    If intMonth >= 1 And intMonth <= 12 Then
        Select Case intMonth
            Case 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12
                ' January, March, May, July, August, October and December
                ' have 31 days.
                If intDay >= 1 And intDay <= 31 Then
                    ReturnStr = intMonth & "/" & intDay & "/" & intYear
                End If
            Case 4, 6, 9, 11
                ' April, June, September and November
                ' have 30 days
                If intDay >= 1 And intDay <= 30 Then
                    ReturnStr = intMonth & "/" & intDay & "/" & intYear
                End If
            Case 2
                ' Depending on whether it is a Leap Year (every four years),
                ' February may have 28 or 29 days.
                If intYear Mod 4 = 0 Then
                    If intDay >= 1 And intDay <= 29 Then
                        ReturnStr = intMonth & "/" & intDay & "/" & intYear
                    End If
                Else
                    If intDay >= 1 And intDay <= 28 Then
                        ReturnStr = intMonth & "/" & intDay & "/" & intYear
                    End If
                End If
        End Select
    End If

    ' Return the recombined string to the calling function.
    GetValidDateString = ReturnStr
End Function
```

There's still obviously going to be some room for error, but I believe this will solve the issue for now.  It's not perfect, but hopefully we'll be able to move away from this VB6 system soon.  Thank you for all of the ideas and suggestions.  They were very helpful in narrowing down the best solution for this specific implementation.